# Tooltips with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following displays tooltips with only ~7 characters per line:

```
img ng-src="images/example.png" tooltip="Site up to date" tooltip-placement="bottom"
```

Tooltips should appear with ~30 characters on each line. All tooltips used elsewhere in our site display correctly.

All tooltips appeared correct until we migrated to [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/).

*I have checked that the error has nothing to do with the tooltip location (in the header), the tooltip source (an img), or the tooltip placement (at the bottom).*

What can I do to make all tooltips appear correctly?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You probably using the Boostrap directives for Angular JS.
This directives has been made for Boostrap 2 version.

**On Boostrap 3 version some of directives not working correctly.**

Check out this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327846/bootstrap-3-with-angularjs)

Comment: What did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: I just use clear Boostrap without Directives or writing my own directives if needed.