# How do I download the Angular UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, github, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I can't believe I have to ask this, but how do I download the Angular UI Grid?

From http://ui-grid.info/:

[image]

After, I click the Download button (above), I get taken here:

[image]

Now what? I don't see a download button. I'm not sure what to do. Somebody please tell me what I must so obviously be missing.

Comment: hit the download zip button on the right side of github and then use whichever JS file you want from that list right there. edit: sorry use this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages and the files are in the `release` folder.

Comment: On another note...I recently had a project where I needed a grid in angular. I had all sorts of issue using ui-grid. This was about a month ago. I found this one to be very easy to implement https://github.com/MoonStorm/trNgGrid

Comment: Thanks. There is no Download Zip button (see my screenshot). So am I just being sent to the wrong github page?

Comment: Yes Bob, use the link from my edit. You basically just need to go up a folder. Take a look at this link regarding grids before you implement ui-grid http://stackoverflow.com/a/23274018/736967

Comment: "You basically just need to go up a folder." That's what I was missing. Which means the original download button sent me to the wrong location. And I'll check out your link. If you'd like to post your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get the Download Zip link when at the ui-grid.info/ github page, not below, such as when viewing ui-grid/release/.

Answer (score 3):

UI Grid is still in beta as of this moment and a lot of stuff is still in flux, non-working links from the front page being part of that... I agree it should be fixed.

The easiest way for now would be to go to the bower repo on github and download the zip for a tag.

Example link: https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/tree/v3.0.0-rc.14
Example zip: https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/archive/v3.0.0-rc.14.zip

Answer (score 3):

Another easy way is to get it here:

- http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js
- http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.min.js
- http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css
- http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.min.css
- http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.woff
- http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.ttf

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using a package manager like Bower. It will make your life easier, and add consistency to your dependency management.

Comment: You should specify in your answer that bower can be used to download angular-ui. At the moment, this doesn't _really_ answer the OP's question.