# How to format the date to be display in ng-grid which is returns from server in json?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid from following link:http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

> My MVC Controller function return data in json format which includes
>   date like this

:
`"RunDate":"\/Date(1439577000000)\/","RunDate":"\/Date(1441391400000)\/"` etc....

My View:

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions" style="min-height:420px"></div>
```

My Grid options in js:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        columnDefs: [{ field: "RunDate", displayName: "Run Date", width: 120, cellFilter: "date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" }],
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
    };
```

I want date to be display in this format:**06/April/2015**

Can anybody help me with this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply custom filter on you variable while binding data. Do use `cellTemplate` of column level.

**Code**

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
 data: 'gridData',
 columnDefs: [{
         field: 'RunDate',
         displayName: 'Run Date',
         cellTemplate： '<span> {{row.entity.RunDate | date:\'dd-MMM-yyyy\'}}</span>'，
     },
     ....
 ]
 });
```

Comment: @MariaPithia `row.entity` contains row level data

Comment: oh ok thanks.what options you would suggest me for displaying data in grid??

Comment: put the code given by me, to your columnDefs of ng-grid option

Comment: pankaj can you suggest me some option instead of ng-grid like i am thinking for kendo grid (with script only)??

Comment: I'd suggest `ui-grid`(updated version of ng-grid)/`smart-table`/ `ng-table`, I don't prefer to go with Kendo..

Comment: can you provide me any good link for that where i can study it and  get code for it and have you used it???

Comment: @MariaPithia do read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375073/best-way-to-represent-a-grid-or-table-in-angularjs-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: i have already checked that link but the answer on it is saying that smart table is good but i have checked and i didnt like it as because there is no good ui and sorting and filtering capability in it

Comment: the link you have given there it is saying smart table.what would you say about it??

Comment: Simply if you are caring about UI, want it  impressive then go for `ui-grid` otherwise go for `Smart Table` which is not that much good in UI

Comment: personally I'd prefer `ui-grid` in terms of UI & good github support on issues

Comment: why you dont prefer kendo ui as though it is having a good ui design ??any performance issue with kendo grid??

Comment: @MariaPithia Initially i tried with it..& found angular variable binding issue with it..May be I missed something in it..but still I don't prefer kendo

Answer (score 2):

Use [Angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), like this:

```
{{row.entity.RunDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}
```

Comment: but where do i do this??

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the date formatting on your `gridOptions`
The correct date format you need is

> `dd/MMM/yyyy`

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enablePinning: true,
        columnDefs: [
                     { field: 'RunDate',displayName: 'Run Date', cellFilter: 'date:\'dd/MMM/yyyy\'' },
                   ]
    };
   ...........
});
```

Check this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2ossdmzRZ2beOwfmi9a?p=preview) for an example