# Angular table to CSV

Tags: angularjs, csv

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table_renderer.html">
    <tr>
    <td>{{node.partcode}}</td>
    <td>{{node.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{node.listprice}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="node in node.components" ng-include="'table_renderer.html'"></tr>
</script>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>Selected Components</tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Partcode</td>
                <td>Qty</td>
                <td>List Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="node in data" ng-include="'table_renderer.html'"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The data contains nested data and this renders the table as required. Is there a simple way of converting this to csv format?

Edit: to clarify, the table rendered by this code is exactly what is required. Ideally, the resultant html would be converted to csv. The correct answer would either indicate that this is not possible, or a solution would be offered.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert your data, or the rendered HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [download csv file from web api in angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300547/download-csv-file-from-web-api-in-angular-js)

Comment: This requirement is to convert the rendered HTML (which also answers Brent's duplicate comment).

Answer (score 0):

you can choose one of [these grid/table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21375073/492258) component to present your data. Each component should have its csv export feature.

My recommendation is [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) and here  [its export example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data)

Comment: I investigated ui-grid, but the requirement to represent nested data isn't neatly covered. The simple table does this, but I need to convert this table to a csv format.