# How to add smart table to angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqgrid

we have implemented jqgrid in our project to view tables, but I want to move the implementation to smart table from angular js, this is the following reference for my conclusion

[Best way to represent a Grid or Table in AngularJS with Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375073/best-way-to-represent-a-grid-or-table-in-angularjs-with-bootstrap-3)

I want to know how do I add the smart table to my angular application, I have downloaded smart table source from

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

it was mentioned that to add this smart table to our application we have to write

```
angular.module('myApp',['smart-table']
```

but how will the application know where is my smart-table source code, I mean do I have to mention path in like this ??

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript" src=" "></script>
```

what should I point the src to ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES.

And u should put the script tag before your definition of angular module.

The src should be where your js file is stored as web resource. Usually relative path to the file or absolute path are both fine.

If u are installing the library with bower or npm, the js file will usually locate in the 'dist' folder in the library's folder.