# Which are good open source Data grid for angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, datagrid, slickgrid, ngx-datatable

In Angularjs we used to use ui-grid. But it's not available in angular 2.
I have tried ngx-datatable but I found some issue with scroll when used with paging.
Ag-grid is not free.
I found angular2 slickgrid by Microsoft, but doesn't found much information, documetation about it.
Does any one know about angular2 slickgrid, has anybody used this?

Comment: actually this problem is preventing us from converting our angularjs application to angular4..we have used ui-grid on a huge scale....

Comment: Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375073/best-way-to-represent-a-grid-or-table-in-angularjs-with-bootstrap-3) for more options

Comment: If you come from UI-Grid, you can take a look at [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) this is the closest you can get in terms of coding and usability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the PrimeNG components to be top quality and free. I use their data table extensively and their data list more recently.

Their data grid is [documented here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datagrid) and [installation instructions here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

Comment: Thanks...This will be very useful..DataTable looks good as per my requirements..I will explore...

Comment: Wow. Two downvotes with no reason! Whoever voted could at least leave a comment stating the reason why, such that we can all learn from your wisdom...